# Makefile.in without Makefile.am in GCC?

Tags: gcc, makefile

I'm reading GCC's source code and have some questions. It's obvious that GCC is build with autotools. But I couldn't find the Makefile.am files required by automake. Is GCC's Makefile.in files written by hand? And if they are written by hand, where can I find the documents describing the syntax of a Makefile.in?

A similar question: [Makefile.in without Makefile.am in projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161847/makefile-in-without-makefile-am-in-projects)

Comment: This is a GNU tool, so if Makefile.in was generated from something, that something would have to be available as well. You have access to the ChangeLog, you can see that changes to Makefile.in appear as "change bla bla", not "regenerate" like configure. You can conclude.

Comment: Yes. But on the other hand, the Makefile.in is really big and hard to read. I've ever doubted that such file was generated automatically by some private maintainer-scripts...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Makefile.am` is a later addition to Autotools family and not all projects use it. GCC in particular does not use it. The top-level `Makefile.in` is generated from `Makefile.tpl` using [autogen](https://www.gnu.org/software/autogen/) (see [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Regenerating_GCC_Configuration) for details). Other `Makefile.in`'s are written by hand according to [Autoconf rules](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Makefile-Substitutions.html#Makefile-Substitutions).

Comment: The top-most directory uses a Makefile.tpl template file. But I couldn't find a similar template file in other subdirectories, for instance, libcpp, there is only   Makefile.in. Is this file written 'by hand'?

Comment: Yes, these other `Makefile.in`s are edited by hand (according to [Autoconf rules](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Makefile-Substitutions.html#Makefile-Substitutions)).

Comment: @noinput Was this answer helpful?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I'm not sure about some internals of GCC. Your answer helps me. I think GCC needs more documentations for beginners to hack, to research.

Comment: Yeah, it's a rough learning curve (but LLVM isn't easy either).